# How to reload data into NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am fairly new to Objective-C and I find there are a lot of tutorials for iOS and UITableView but almost none for OS X Apps via NSTableView.  I have built a method to retrieve my data but I get an error on the last line:

"Property tableView not found on object type ProductsViewController".

I do not know the correct way to reload my data into my table or if I even need to use an NSTableView for this specific instance?  Is there a better way to display my data than using NSTableView?

```
#import "ProductsViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"

#define getDataURL @"http://myurl"


@interface ProductsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductsViewController

@synthesize jsonArray, productsArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



[self retrieveData];



}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTable:(NSTableView *)tableView{

return productsArray.count;
}

- (void) retrieveData{

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

productsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++){

    NSString * pID          = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * pName        = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_name"];
    NSString * pPrice       = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_price"];
    NSString * pDescription = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_description"];
    NSString * pImage       = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_image"];
    NSString * pDownload    = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_download"];
    NSString * pVideo       = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_video"];
    NSString * pFeatured    = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"featured"];


    [productsArray addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProduct_Name: pName andProduct_Price:pPrice andProduct_Description:pDescription andProduct_Image:pImage andProduct_Download:pDownload andProduct_Video:pVideo andProduct_Featured:pFeatured andProduct_ID:pID]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Of course you need an `NSTableView` and a few more data source / delegate methods or Cocoa Bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the required delegate methods for the [`NSTableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdatasource?language=objc) protocol. Specifically, you need these two:

```
numberOfRowsInTableView:
tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
```

The table view will then call these methods for the data it wants.

In addition, there's [a great tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118835/os-x-nstableview-tutorial) over at raywenderlich.com about using NSTableViews.

Comment: Thats perfect.  Thank you so much!